# Remove display-posts link post from users who do not have access this post

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I want to remove the link of the posts from post lists where user have no permission to access.

my page show all the post link. but i want to show all the tittle of the post but certain post only text without link because user do not have permission.

my post list are the quiz. I want to user finish first quiz before can access the second quiz.

Current condition, if user access second quiz before finish first quiz it's direct to error page. but i want to remove the link to error page so only text appear.

But not all link. My Code to show lists

```
    function favourites_content() {
echo do_shortcode ('[display-posts post_type="unit" meta_key="module-tag" meta_value="Summer Session" orderby="date" order="ASC"]');
            }
```

Comment: which user are not having the permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to just place your role name instead of author in if condition.

```
function favourites_content() {
 $user = wp_get_current_user();
 if ( in_array( 'author', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
    echo do_shortcode ('[display-posts post_type="unit" meta_key="module-tag" meta_value="Summer Session" orderby="date" order="ASC"]');
 }else
 {

    echo "Please do the login to for edit the post";
 }
}
```